# Spring annotation based bean injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations

So this is basically what I am trying to achieve: Inject User with constructor into UserClass. But it is throwing "No default constructor found" error. As I suspect if I add `@Autowired` to class User constructor it expects injection there so I'm not really sure where the problem is.

The question might be too basic so you can redirect me to older such questions. There is very little information on annotation based DI.

```
@Component
public class UserClass {

    public User user;

    @Autowired
    public UserClass(User user) {
        this.user = user; 
    }
}

@Configuration
public class DIconfig {

    @Bean
    public User getUser() {
        return new User('John');
    }
}

@Component
public class User {

    public String name;

    //@Autowired
    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define two beans of the class User, one with `@Component`, and one with `@Bean`. The bean configuration with `@Bean` is fine so far, however the bean definition with `@Component` is indeed lacking the default constructor. Every bean which is defined with `@Component` must either have a default constructor or a constructor where all dependencies are autowired. Neither is the case with your bean. So either add a default constructor or remove the `@Component` and only create beans of that class with an `@Bean` method.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So if I understand correctly injecting via Bean and Component are two ways of doing it. What is the difference? Thank you

Comment: There is no difference in the result, both methods create the same type of beans. However, `@Bean` is usually used to create beans for classes, where you are not able to put an `@Component` on the class (because the class comes from a framework for example) or if the bean needs some custom initialization.